# Get array values from next keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to show a specific order when I click on the key. When I click on '5', the result would be '5,6,4'. When I click on '6', I would get '6,4,5'.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this array sorted ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the values until the clicked value to another array say - `$frontArray` and merge it to the main array.

```
//get the clicked value
$clickedValue = your clicked value;
//find the key
$key = array_search($clickedValue, $myArray);

$frontArray = array();
if ($key !== FALSE) {
  $keyReached = FALSE;
  foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
    if ($key == $k) {
      $keyReached = TRUE;
    }
    if (!$keyReached) {
      $frontArray[] = $v;
      unset($myArray[$k]);
    }
  }
  $myArray = array_merge($myArray, $frontArray);

  //re-index the array
  $myArray = array_values($myArray);
}

print_r($myArray); // this gets modified as per the clicked value
```

I've tested this using your example and it works fine.

Comment: thanks jitendrapurohit for give me answer .but when i click on 5 then get '5,4,6' but i need result '5,6,4'.

Comment: @RaxShah I've updated the answer, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_splice to split array to two - before and after

```
$ar = [4,5,6];

$v = 5;
if (false !== ($i = array_search($v, $ar)) {
    $b = array_splice($ar, $i+1);
    $ar = array_merge($b, $ar);
}

print($ar);
```